# Orderby dictionary like data structure by value angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I’m trying to order an object data structure by the value.
{apple: 1, pear: 85, orange: 24, blueberry: 18}

I want to achieve a reorder by value in DESC order. I don’t think there is a a method to do so, even if this object was wrapped in an Array, but wanted to check.

My other thought process was to separate the key value pair into 2 separate arrays. Then loop the value array, search for the max vale and capture the index at that point and that particular index should match at the key array. Then i can move the key/value pair into a third/separate array keeping order by max value. Then based on the index number captured, pop from both the key and value array.

If there is a better method please feel free to share?

Comment: Dictionaries (hashtables, maps, etc) are generally not ordered - it's inherent in the way hashtables are implemented (either by key or by value). What you'll want to do is copy the values into an array (which does have order) and then sort it using a custom comparator if your values are non-scalar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `Object`'s keys are not sorted, so you will not be able to achieve what you want with just an Object.

If you use an Array, however, you can use [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```js
const myArray = [{apple: 1}, {pear: 85}, {orange: 24}, {blueberry: 18}]
myArray.sort((e1, e2) => Object.values(e2)[0] - Object.values(e1)[0])
console.log(myArray)
```

Comment: I get this error: Argument of type '(e1: any, e2: any) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: any, b: any) => number'.
  Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Comment: this is an example of the array with objects:::: [{assailing: 1},{haters: 1},{trump: 10}]

Comment: Could this error be caused by a number in the key position? For example, i have some values (not mentioned in my example) like [{2018: 10}, { 2: 14}, {men: 3}] and so on..

Comment: I edited my answer to correct the comparaison function. The problem was that Array.sort expects `(x, y) => number` and not `(x, y) => boolean`.

Comment: so does that loop the array and each time value to the right is larger than to the left it places it above ?